# How can I remove burg themes?

Tags: package-management

Please help. I downloaded several Burg themes using Super-Boot-Manager. Later I deleted Super-Boot_Manager. Now all the Burg themes have become redundant, but blocking any update through Synaptic.

I cannot even remove these themes whatever I may try to do. How can I remove these Burg themes?
[image]

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/465406_10150643256116733_555216732_9413193_1648842725_o.jpg?dl=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by adding a new burg repository Thanks for the help from members. of [ubuntu kerala group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ubuntukerala/)

Answer (score 0):

This should remove them:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
```

Comment: sorry it wont work

Comment: you may have to use "find | grep" remove one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove themes without removing the BURG Bootloader.

Just open a terminal (Alt+F2) And Type:

```
gksu nautilus
```

or

```
sudo nautilus
```

And navigate to the Root Drive.
Navigate to boot/burg/themes.

And Move all of the theme folders to the trash you wish delete.

However, **Do Not** Delete **All** of the Themes in the boot/burg/theme folder.
Leave one theme in the boot/burg/themes folder.

Or you can Delete all the theme folders in the /boot/burg/themes Folder,
**And** Download at least one theme and extract the zip file. Then, Open a terminal and type

```
gksu nautilus
```

Or

```
sudo nautilus
```

and navigate to the folder where you extracted the theme folder.
Move it to the /boot/burg/themes folder.

And finally, run this in a terminal:

```
sudo update-burg
```